# i want to make a search engine in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm making a website for Market and I want to create a search engine for it LIKE when I type a name of fruit I should get all the information for it , I already have a search bar in the top of each page but whenever I press it I get an error

Comment: Visual studio code is not a programming language. And I can't understand you want to make a search engine like google or you want to make a search bar to people can search for products of your market. So first tell us, what programming language are you going to use and are you going to make a search engine or a search system for your own website?

Comment: Maybe it will work if you try a different editor, Vim, Sublime, Notepad, Notepad++, Gedit, Kedit, ed, Eclipse